# What is rotationally invariant crossover in Evolutionary optimization algorithms?

Tags: evolutionary-algorithms

This article ["Enhancing Differential Evolution Utilizing Eigenvector-Based Crossover Operator"](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6698290/) design a rotationally invariant crossover, what is, in simple words, rotationally invariant crossover in Evolutionary optimization algorithms? I appreciate if anyone can show me graphically.

Comment: Should be *rotationally invariant* not "rationally invariant"